# PHP script that opens powershell and powershell opens excel

Tags: php, powershell

Can someone help me understand why this php script isn't able to make the excel instance visible

If I run the same command from CMD prompt it works. When I run it through php it opens the excel application but it never becomes visible

```
<?php
    $k = "powershell -command \"start-process powershell -argumentlist '\$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;\$Excel.Visible = \$true;sleep 10' -wait\"";
    echo $k;
    echo system($k);
?>
```

Comment: Are you running the PHP on a webserver?

Comment: Both windows server and windows 10, testing on windows 10 with IIS now and also have it on window server with IIS, not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question

Comment: If you're running something in a webserver then it doesn't have a graphical user session where it can open an application. And if it's on a remote server it wouldn't be able to open anything on the local machine where the user and their browser are located. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve with this code?